# How to clean WebSphere Application server's cache?

Tags: caching, websphere-liberty

I am using an old WebSphere Application server version 8.5.5.9 in Windows 10. I tried to upgrade it to the latest version but my old application doesn't start up due to some dependency on the old version of WebSphere. The problem I am facing that my latest code deployment doesn't show the latest changes. It shows some old previous stuff. I am guessing WebSphere cache my application class files somewhere. When I google how to clean the Websphere application server's cache? I found some link as:-

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/200115/how-do-i-clean-the-websphere-application-servers-c/

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21607887

Those mentioned files do not exist. I downloaded WebSphere from this link:-

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24041819#LibertyZip

So how do I clean server cache for this particular version? I am guessing to get the latest code deployment should work if I could clean the server caches. I am not sure. So please advice me how do I get the latest code deployed to WebSphere?

Answer (score 3):

Based off of your last link and your stackoverflow tag, it sounds like you're using WebSphere Liberty and not traditional WebSphere.  However, the first two links regarding clearing cache refer to how to do it in traditional WebSphere instead of Liberty.

In Liberty, you want to run the server start (or run) command with --clean appended to it, like:

```
server start {serverName} --clean
```

Full documentation is here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_command_server.html

Also, you are correct that (thanks to WebSphere Liberty's zero migration), you should be able to redeploy your app to the newest version of Liberty without making any changes (as long as you don't make any configuration changes).

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear JVM class cache as well as OSGI class cache. Here is a very well explained article on [how to clear the cache in websphere.](https://aspsqltutorials.blogspot.com/2019/03/how-to-clear-cache-in-was-websphere.html)